# Vue: if data is a function, how to update the data?

Tags: vue.js

I'm going through the Style Guide for Vue JS and for this section https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-data-essential

The recommendation is for the data object to return a function.
The given example is as below:

```
Vue.component('some-comp', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
})
```

In my recent experimentations with Vue, my data is an object.

My question is that, how do I then modify that data?

Currently I would just have a method like so:

```
methods: {
  updateFoo() {
    this.foo = 'newValue';
  }
}
```

Comment: did you get any problem to change `this.foo` ? I think both will work

Answer (score 1):

Making `data` a function doesn't change anything. And it's not a recommendation, it doesn't work otherwise. But it's very simple...

Take this...

```
data : { foo : 'bar'}
```

and make it this...

```
data(){
    return { foo : 'bar'}
}
```

When you ask how to modify it, inside your vue component, you can do just as you say... `this.foo = 'new value'`. But, instead of providing a literal value, you can also provide a variable that already exists in global scope. That way, your component will update to reflect any changes in the watched variable. The trick here is to never replace the 'root' watched object, but to modify it's properties. So...

```
// in window scope
var vueStore = { foo : 'bar' }

// then in your component....
data(){
    return { vueStore : vueStore }
}

// then from anywhere in your application
vueStore.foo = 'bar'
// or, inside vue methods
this.vueStore.foo = 'bar'


// BUT NEVER DO THIS once vue is initialized...
vueStore = ...
```

Comment: you would still want to not share the vuestore between multiple instances of the component though?

Comment: Oh sure. Why not? Share it with everything that needs it. The wisdom says that simple javascript objects as shared stores get messy when there are so many components modifying them that you lose track of where a modification is coming from. In practice, shared state is read often but usually modified in just one or two places, and it is much cleaner to extract it like this than to try and encapsulate it and pass it around to wherever it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood It a bit.

`data` should be function that returns an object - only in case you are dealing with component.In case It's standard Vue instance, you can just use plain `data` object

```
data: {}
```

So, If function returns an object, you are still able to access `data` properties like this, without any problem:

```
  updateFoo() {
    this.foo = 'newValue';
  }
```

Comment: by 'still able to access', you also mean I can still update the value in the same way?

Comment: @nxmohamad yes.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using vue components as per documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function). component should have data as function with return type of object. But if you're not using components then data should be object. At the end both can be updated same way.

First way is using methods as you have done in question.

```
methods: { updateFoo() { this.foo = 'newValue'; } }
```

Second way is update property directly on events. For eg.

```
<button type="button" @click="foo = 'new value'">Update</button>
```

Also you can update property in some other hooks like methods, created, mounted, etc. using `this.foo` with assignment call.